# Spring bean load error using spring-data-mongodb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

We are using Spring version 3.2.0 and now introducing spring-data-mongodb version 1.4.0 in the codebase. I tried to write a new spring config file (mongo-config.xml) while solely defines mongodb related beans.

My Spring config is as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.4.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<mongo:mongoid="replicaSetMongo"replica-set="localhost:10901,localhost:10902">
<mongo:optionsconnections-per-host="8"
ssl="false" />
</mongo:mongo>

<mongo:db-factoryid="xmlLogDbFactory"
mongo-ref="replicaSetMongo"
dbname="logs"
username="logs_owner"
password="logs_owner" />

<mongo:mapping-converter>
<mongo:custom-converters>
<mongo:converter>
<beanclass="com.utils.mongodb.dao.impl.SspLogsWriteConver ter"/>
</mongo:converter>
</mongo:custom-converters>
</mongo:mapping-converter>

<beanid="xmlLogTemplate"class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTempla te">
<constructor-argname="mongoDbFactory"ref="xmlLogDbFactory"/>
<constructor-argname="mongoConverter"ref="mappingConverter"/>
<propertyname="writeConcern">
<util:constantstatic-field="com.mongodb.WriteConcern.UNACKNOWLEDGED"/>
</property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

I deployed the application on JBoss. But JBoss given errors on startup as follows. Can someone help me what is going wrong? 
Is there a mismatch between spring version & spring-mongodb version? I noticed that the exception trace mentions spring-beans-3.2.0 jar even though the issue is with mongo-config.xml

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefi nitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location [mongo-config.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [spring/commonUtil-config.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionSt oreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [spring/mongo-config.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid NamespaceHandler class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.MongoNames paceHandler] for namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo]: problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/repository/config/RepositoryConfigurationExtension
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFast ProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java :68) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderCo ntext.error(ReaderContext.java:85) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderCo ntext.error(ReaderContext.java:76) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanD efinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResour ce(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:271) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanD efinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(Defaul tBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:196) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanD efinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(Defau ltBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:181) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanD efinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions( DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:140) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanD efinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(De faultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:111) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefin itionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinit ionReader.java:493) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefin itionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitio nReader.java:390) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefin itionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionR eader.java:334) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefin itionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionR eader.java:302) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanD efinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResour ce(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:255) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
... 36 more
```

Comment: You seem to be missing this class `org/springframework/data/repository/config/RepositoryConfigurationExtension` from your classpath.

Comment: @Sotirios : This class is part of spring-data-mongodb-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar which is already present in my WEB-INF/lib folder.

Comment: No, it's from spring-data-commons

Comment: I think the issue is that this class is part of more than one jar. How do I resolve it?
jar tvf ../standalone/deployments/app-ws.war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-data-mongodb-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar | grep RepositoryConfigurationExtension
  3139 Fri Feb 08 04:14:40 PST 2013 org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/config/MongoRepositoryConfigurationExtension.class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved now. I realized that when spring-data-mongodb version 1.4 jar was downloaded by maven, there was another jar downloaded in my repository: spring-data-commons version 1.7.

I copied this second jar to my WEB-INF/lib folder, and the application started working.